# How do i write my form code for 3rd nested model in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on an app where i nested the 3 model

```
resources :genres do
    resources :stories do
        resources :episodes
    end
end
```

Meanwhile, i've been able to write the form for genres and stories as in

```
<%= form_for(genre) do |f| %>
 <% if genre.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(genre.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this genre from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% genre.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

and stories

```
<%= form_for([@genre, @genre.stories.build]) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :summary %>
    <%= f.text_area :summary %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Can someone pls tell me how to write the form for episodes...

When i wrote this

```
<%= form_for([@genre.stories, @genre.@stories.episodes.build]) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I got this error

syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting '(' ...@genre.stories, @genre.@stories.episodes.build]) do |f| @out... ... ^ C:/Users/Adegbite/Documents/Apps/twiliste2/app/views/episodes/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting keyword_end ...@genre.@stories.episodes.build]) do |f| @output_buffer.safe_... ... ^ C:/Users/Adegbite/Documents/Apps/twiliste2/app/views/episodes/_form.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Thanks.

Comment: Curious if the answer I provided was helpful...

Comment: Yes, jvillian... My bad. I dont know why i'm unable to vote up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
<%= form_for([@genre.stories, @genre.@stories.episodes.build]) do |f| %>
```

Should be more like:

```
<%= form_for([@genre, @story, @story.episodes.build]) do |f| %>
```

Of course, you'll have to set `@genre` and `@story` appropriately in the `new` action of your `EpisodesController`.

BTW, `@genre.@stories` makes no sense and is not valid. `@stories` is an instance variable which, presumably, contains (or would contain) one or more stories. `.stories` is a method call on an instance of `Genre`. `.@stories` is nothing.